# Compiling fbexport under FreeBSD 10

Tags: c++, gcc, freebsd, llvm-gcc

I am attempting to compile fbexport (Firebird export/import tool) under FreeBSD10. GCC, binutils are installed. In make.conf:

```
CC=gcc47
CXX=g++47
CPP=cpp47
USE_GCC=any
```

But `cd /tmp/fbexport-1.90 && make` generate error:

```
# make
g++ -c -O1 -DIBPP_LINUX -DIBPP_GCC -Iibpp -o fbcopy/args.o fbcopy/args.cpp
make: exec(g++) failed (No such file or directory)
*** Error code 1

Stop.
make: stopped in /tmp/fbexport-1.90
```

Then I changed Makefile and replaced g++ with g++47, but error:

```
# make exe/fbexport
g++47 -c -O1 -DIBPP_LINUX -DIBPP_GCC -Iibpp -o fbexport/ParseArgs.o fbexport/ParseArgs.cpp
g++47 -c -O1 -DIBPP_LINUX -DIBPP_GCC -Iibpp -o fbexport/FBExport.o fbexport/FBExport.cpp
fbexport/FBExport.cpp: In member function 'std::string FBExport::CreateHumanString(IBPP::Statement&, int)':
fbexport/FBExport.cpp:339:31: error: 'gcvt' was not declared in this scope
fbexport/FBExport.cpp: In member function 'bool FBExport::CreateString(IBPP::Statement&, int, std::string&)':
fbexport/FBExport.cpp:452:31: error: 'gcvt' was not declared in this scope
*** Error code 1

Stop.
make: stopped in /tmp/fbexport-1.90
```

So, need some help.

Comment: I have just sent email to author. He said this is the bug and added it to bugtracker. See his page on the GitHub. Thanks. Question is closed.

Comment: Please add your comment as an answer and accept it. Or delete the question altogether. Otherwise it will stay visible as unanswered.